# Ethernet/router work separately. Connection drops when both connected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

My internet connection drops when I connect my desktop to ethernet through the router. If I connect wirelessly through the router or via ethernet by plugging the network box (I am in an apartment) connection directly into my room instead of the router, then everything works fine. But as soon as I go from network box > router > desktop the connection drops. Once it drops, if I disconnect everything and then connect via either of the two working methods, the connection is still broken for a few minutes until it recovers on its own. If I unplug everything while it's working and re-connect with either supported method, I have internet almost immediately. So it seems like once I get into this invalid configuration some other piece of hardware down the line might be throwing a fit and need to recover.

Even if something down the line isn't handling this configuration gracefully though, given that everything works as long as I'm not chaining the two, maybe I'm doing something wrong on my end. A Google search suggests that this may be a power-saving optimization by the OS, but this happens even if I disable all power saving settings in Device Manager for my ethernet adapter, and in addition to the same desktop working fine with a direct ethernet connection, I never had this issue with the same desktop another apartment (internet via router->wall as well). Is there anything else on my end that could be causing this?

Edit: when connected from router ethernet to desktop, the internet works fine until it starts consuming 100-200 Mbps down. Then it flatlines and disconnects. The connection only seems to repair itself if I plug the yellow cable coming from the box to the room the desktop is in & into the desktop. If I just disconnect the ethernet cable coming out of the router & restart the router (yellow cable going into the router), the connection remains broken for even 5ish minutes.

#### Hardware

Router: [TP-Link AC1750 (Archer A7)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079JD7F7G)
Switch Mode: Router (not Access Point, only other option)

Ethernet cable (from router to room & room port to desktop): [Cat6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00C2B81K6)

Ethernet cable (from box): ISO/IEC 11801 4PR/24 TYPE CMR (ETL) CHC 9700851

Internet speed: Gigabit (though actual speed is closer to 800ish down / 900ish up Mbps connected directly to wall)

IP config results in various modes of connection: https://pastebin.com/raw/rs8LTjBH

Detailed pictures of network box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiGml.jpg

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "network box".  can you help me understand?

Comment: @FrankThomas https://i.imgur.com/60hxHqU.jpg

Comment: ok so that looks to be a patch panel for in-wall wiring, but its too fuzzy when zoomed in to tell what hardware is actually in there other than the patch panels. I have to assume there is a switch in there, and it looks like there's a multi-port modem,  but having trouble telling much else (like a router).

Comment: so when you put your router in-line, by plugging the live ethernet for your apartment into the blue plug, and then jack the desktop into the yellow, right? so what IP address do you get when you connect without the router, with the router over Wifi, and when you connect the network? once the network breaks, whats the wan IP on the tplink? your router is in router (not bridge or AP) mode, right? In part I'm trying to tell if there is a router between you and the ISP other than your TPLink.

Comment: @FrankThomas the router is in Router mode. The only other option is Access Point. I have attached more pictures of the box (router was sitting on a shelf above it) & ipconfig information to the question